# Heroku bundler ignores bson

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, heroku

I'm trying to deploy on heroku a rails app that uses mongodb with mongoid. Everything works great locally, but when I deploy it (the heroku server starts fine), I get an error that the 'bson' gem cannot be found:

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongo-1.3.1/lib/mongo.rb:56:in `require': no such file to load -- bson (LoadError)
```

What's weird is that I explicitly include it in my gemfile. Bundler installs the bson gem when I run 'bundle install' locally, but when I 'git push heroku master' to init the app, heroku's bundler completely ignores the bson gem -- it installs mongo, mongoid, and everything except bson.

Here's my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
gem 'mongo'
gem 'bson'
gem 'mongoid'

group :development do
  gem 'therubyrhino'
end

group :assets do
  gem "less-rails" #Sprockets (what Rails 3.1 uses for its asset pipeline) supports LESS
  gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'devise'

gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
```

And when I run 'heroku run bundle install':

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Using rake (10.0.3) 
Using i18n (0.6.1) 
Using multi_json (1.5.0) 
Using activesupport (3.2.11) 
Using builder (3.0.4) 
Using activemodel (3.2.11) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using journey (1.0.4) 
Using rack (1.4.4) 
Using rack-cache (1.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
Using hike (1.2.1) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Using sprockets (2.2.2) 
Using actionpack (3.2.11) 
Using mime-types (1.19) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.12) 
Using mail (2.4.4) 
Using actionmailer (3.2.11) 
Using arel (3.0.2) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.35) 
Using activerecord (3.2.11) 
Using activeresource (3.2.11) 
Using bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.4.0) 
Using execjs (1.4.0) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2) 
Using json (1.7.6) 
Using rdoc (3.12) 
Using thor (0.16.0) 
Using railties (3.2.11) 
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2) 
Using commonjs (0.2.6) 
Using orm_adapter (0.4.0) 
Using warden (1.2.1) 
Using devise (2.2.1) 
Using multipart-post (1.1.5) 
Using faraday (0.8.4) 
Using hashie (1.2.0) 
Using httpauth (0.2.0) 
Using jquery-rails (2.1.4) 
Using jwt (0.1.5) 
Using less (2.2.2) 
Using less-rails (2.2.6) 
Using mongo (1.3.1) 
Using moped (1.3.2) 
Using origin (1.0.11) 
Using mongoid (3.0.17) 
Using oauth2 (0.8.0) 
Using omniauth (1.1.1) 
Using omniauth-oauth2 (1.1.1) 
Using omniauth-facebook (1.4.1) 
Using bundler (1.3.0.pre.5) 
Using rails (3.2.11) 
Using sass (3.2.5) 
Using sass-rails (3.2.5) 
Using twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.2.0) 
Using uglifier (1.3.0) 
Cannot write a changed lockfile while frozen.
Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
```

Notice that it is not "Using bson (1.3.1)" like it is when I run bundle install locally:

```
Using rake (10.0.3) 
Using i18n (0.6.1) 
Using multi_json (1.5.0) 
Using activesupport (3.2.11) 
Using builder (3.0.4) 
Using activemodel (3.2.11) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using journey (1.0.4) 
Using rack (1.4.4) 
Using rack-cache (1.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
Using hike (1.2.1) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Using sprockets (2.2.2) 
Using actionpack (3.2.11) 
Using mime-types (1.19) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.12) 
Using mail (2.4.4) 
Using actionmailer (3.2.11) 
Using arel (3.0.2) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.35) 
Using activerecord (3.2.11) 
Using activeresource (3.2.11) 
Using bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1) 
Using bson (1.3.1) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.4.0) 
Using execjs (1.4.0) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2) 
Using json (1.7.6) 
Using rdoc (3.12) 
Using thor (0.16.0) 
Using railties (3.2.11) 
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2) 
Using commonjs (0.2.6) 
Using orm_adapter (0.4.0) 
Using warden (1.2.1) 
Using devise (2.2.1) 
Using multipart-post (1.1.5) 
Using faraday (0.8.4) 
Using hashie (1.2.0) 
Using httpauth (0.2.0) 
Using jquery-rails (2.1.4) 
Using jwt (0.1.5) 
Using less (2.2.2) 
Using less-rails (2.2.6) 
Using mongo (1.3.1) 
Using moped (1.3.2) 
Using origin (1.0.11) 
Using mongoid (3.0.17) 
Using oauth2 (0.8.0) 
Using omniauth (1.1.1) 
Using omniauth-oauth2 (1.1.1) 
Using omniauth-facebook (1.4.1) 
Using bundler (1.2.3) 
Using rails (3.2.11) 
Using sass (3.2.5) 
Using sass-rails (3.2.5) 
Using therubyrhino_jar (1.7.4) 
Using therubyrhino (2.0.2) 
Using twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.2.0) 
Using uglifier (1.3.0) 
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Is there some crazy filter on heroku's bundler? Everything seems to work fine, except that it just completely ignores bson's presence in the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock.

Note: I am using jruby locally, just like heroku does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing `bson` and `mongo` from your Gemfile. They are not needed by Mongoid versions 3 and above, which now use [moped](http://mongoid.org/en/moped) for the BSON implementation and MongoDB driver.

**Edit**

It occurred to me that you may intentionally be using the driver provided by `mongo` in parallel with Mongoid. If that is the case, maybe you can port your `mongo` calls to `moped`. I'm not sure how feasible this is. It depends on how you are using it.

If you decide you still want to use both drivers concurrently, there may be a clue in your bundler output. It looks like you and Heroku are not using the same version of `bundler`:

```
< Using bundler (1.3.0.pre.5) 
---
> Using bundler (1.2.3)
```

Comment: Yes! The problem was that I was calling `gem 'mongo'`. I also realized (by running `heroku run ruby -v`), that my heroku stack uses ruby 1.9.3, not jruby, at least with some things.